# Ubuntu 20.04 keyboard media keys do not work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, media-buttons

I have a Dell keyboard. It has `PlayPause`, `Next` and `Previous` buttons for media-controlling, but they don't work at all.
I tried many recommended solutions, but none of them work.
In `KeyboardShortcuts` when I click on, for example play/pause, and then hit the play button on my keyboard, it sets something, but it does not work in any media players. I also try `dconf-editor` but when I set them, again they don't work.
When I run `xev` in terminal and press for example my play button on my keyboard, I get this:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  125 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

When I try with `showkey -a` I get this:

```
^M   13 0015 0x0d
^M   13 0015 0x0d
^M   13 0015 0x0d
^M   13 0015 0x0d
^M   13 0015 0x0d
^M   13 0015 0x0d
```

It means that only other keys (here enter) fetched.
Also, when I run `sudo showkey -k` I get this:

```
keycode 164 press
keycode 164 release
keycode 163 press
keycode 163 release
keycode 165 press
keycode 165 release
```

How can I set my keyboard keys to control my media?

Comment: I have a Logitech PS2 media keyboard which worked perfectly in 18.04 but not in 20.04 with either Videos or VLC although the Mute, volume ▲ and ▼ keys work fine. Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my media keys problem on Ubuntu 20.04.1

By default the Media Play button is not set on 20.04 out of the box.

Go to Settings → Keyboard Shortcuts and move down the list to the Sound and Media section and navigate down the list to `Play (or play/Pause)` which will open the set key dialogue box

[image]

[image]

Once there, press the <kbd>Home Page</kbd> (WWW) button to set it and finish off by selecting <kbd>Set</kbd>

Comment: On my system, the key shortcuts were already set, although in the Sound and Media category (difference Unity vs Gnome?). Even after removing and re-assigning them, it didn't work.

Comment: @hsandt For me it works only for the app that was opened "first". For example when i open Spotify after Chrome browser, Spotify does not react to the keys. I have to close the browser and then it works..